# Why character value is not taking after integer value in c

Tags: c

So this is my c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a;
    char b;
    printf("Enter input \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter char input \n");
    scanf("%c", &b);
    printf("%d,%c", a, b);
}
```

And I'm getting output as

```
Enter input 
3
Enter char input 
3,
```

Can you explain me why its not taking character value the second time. This program works well if i take charcter input first.

Comment: There's a newline character left in the input stream after the first `scanf`; the second, with the `%c` format, reads that as its input. Add a space before the format specifier: `scanf(" %c", &b);` to fix. This has been answered in other posts; looking for a good one...

Comment: I didn't gave space earlier.

Answer (score 0):

you are entering space or enter button after integer input, So **b** is assigned that space/enter.

add **getchar();** before input **b**